# Accessing Kubernetes API using username and password

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I'm am currently configuring Heketi Server (Deployed on K8S clusterA) to interact with my Glusterfs cluster that is deployed as a DaemonSet on another K8S cluster ClusterB.

One of the configurations required by Heketi to connect to GlusterFS K8S cluster are :

```
    "kubeexec": {
      "host" :"https://<URL-OF-CLUSTER-WITH-GLUSTERFS>:6443",
      "cert" : "<CERTIFICATE-OF-CLUSTER-WITH-GLUSTERFS>",
      "insecure": false,
      "user": "WHERE_DO_I_GET_THIS_FROM",
      "password": "<WHERE_DO_I_GET_THIS_FROM>",
      "namespace": "default",
      "backup_lvm_metadata": false
    },
```

As you can see, it requires a user and password. I have no idea where to get that from. 
One thing that comes to mind is creating a service account on ClusterB and using the token to authenticate but Heketi does not seem to be taking that as an authentication mechanism.

The cert is something that I got from `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/kube-ca.crt` but I have no idea where to get the user/password from. Any idea what could be done?

If I do a `kubectl config view` I only see certificates for the admin user of my cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could only mean one thing: [basic HTTP auth](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-password-file).

You can specify a username/password in a file when you start the kube-apiserver with the `--basic-auth-file=SOMEFILE` option.

Comment: what should I write in SOMEFILE

Comment: Standard is md5 passwords like what you can generate with this: http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html